# ibm-cloud RuntimeException: Error while fetching access token from token service

Tags: ibm-cloud

RuntimeException: Error while fetching access token from token service

Came out and crush my app...

I am using an ibm cloud lite account.
The api key and url are correct.
Even if I tried to create another account, it was the same error.

code

```
    microphoneHelper = new MicrophoneHelper(act);

    speechService = new SpeechToText(new IamAuthenticator("[MY API KEY]"));
    speechService.setServiceUrl("https://api.kr-seo.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com");

    findViewById(R.id.btn_test).setOnClickListener(v->{

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    RecognizeOptions param = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                            .audio(capture)
                            .speakerLabels(true)
                            .contentType(ContentType.OPUS.toString())
                            .model("ko-KR_NarrowbandModel")
                            .interimResults(true)
                            .inactivityTimeout(2000)
                            .build();
                    speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(param, new MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showError(e);
                }

            }
        }).start();

}
```

Comment: Add details: Which compute, which runtime, which region, which app, what code...?

Comment: android sdk, in south korea

Comment: implementation 'com.ibm.watson:speech-to-text:8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.5.0'

Comment: was you able to find the answer, I am getting same error